# Connect to facebook api in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

i found an sdk here:

**http://www.baskoro.web.id/facebook-connect-blackberry-HOWTO.html**

i tried to run the code both on device and simulator but it shows only white screen and nothing else

i also tried this without result token:

**.append("&next=http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_permissions.php?api_key=" + "api_key" + "&display=popup&v=1.0&next=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?xxRESULTTOKENxx&fbconnect=true&ext_perm=read_stre...")**

but no success

i also tried this without result token:

**StringBuffer url = new StringBuffer()
            .append("http://m.facebook.com/login.php?")
            .append("api_key=")
            .append(facebookFacade.getApplicationKey())
            .append("&connect_display=page")
            .append("&v=1.0")
            .append("&fbconnect=true")
            .append(
                    "&next="http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?xxRESULTTOKENxx&fbconnect=true"
                    );**

i dont have result token
how to get that????

Plzzzzzzzz help

Answer (score 1):

Please use the latest SDK at [here](http://www.baskoro.web.id/facebook-blackberry-sdk.html) instead. You should be able to follow the short tutorial on the same page as well.

Answer (score 1):

Download graph api from http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/.
After that you have to add two thinks.

one is when you want to post a photo to your friends wall ,you have to put one more key-value in the JSONObject(Request) - that is  requestObject.put("target_id",getid()) in publisePhoto method facebookuser.java & facebook.java

Second is you have to change 
JSONObject responseObject = fb.write(getId() + "/photos", requestObject, pPhoto.getMIMEType(), imageData, true);

to

JSONObject responseObject = fb.write(getId() + "/photos?access_token="+Facebook.token, requestObject, pPhoto.getMIMEType(), imageData, true);in FacebookUser.java & Facebook.java

where token is Static string from Facebook.java and store the value of access_token (you have to add it)

Answer (score 0):

i think before you start with sample codes.
you need to study some of the links.

1. [OAuth 2.0](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-10)
2. [facebook developer documents](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/)

after that you can get

client_id and client_secret from [this link](http://developers.facebook.com/setup/)

Comment: hey Vivart i checked the graph Api and i have api_key,secret_key,application_id with me but still i don't understand how to use the url mentioned in graph api as they ask for auth token.i dont have and how can i get that?