# Blackberry facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, blackberry, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connect to facebook api in blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429600/connect-to-facebook-api-in-blackberry)

I'm building an app for BB, and need to connect to FB (when I click a button in my app) to authenticate and post some info onto FB's Wall. I searched around and found BB Facebook SDK, but could not find document how to use it.
Would anyone have a working example Java code for this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I posted the link as well as some changes required to do in that api in [Connect to facebook api in blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429600/connect-to-facebook-api-in-blackberry/6157068#6157068).

I think it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this link to download sdk -- http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/
unzip the downloaded -- FacebookBlackBerrySDK-0.8.25-bin.zip
Read -- `README.pdf` -- in the unzipped packaged.
The instruction are there how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the included Strawberry demo for example code. As far as I've been able to find in the past, there is no good documentation. Even the included README.PDF is incredibly light when it comes to API or anything. In this case it's honestly a matter of reading through that demo and trying to figure it out.